# Pull certain info out of textfile

Tags: c#, text

so I have a text file just a file full of emails and passwords on personal accounts of mine (the programs for storing usernames and passwords) the format the text file in is weird like:

```
"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com"
```

How would I pull out he password and my email from this?

How would I create a loop to grab the email out of them, then the corresponding password that goes along with it - into like an output text file? I;m assuming something with Regular Expressions which I am terrible at so, yea. Any help is appreciated thank you guys.

I don't really know, but I attempted it at least:

```
string source = File.ReadAllText("FilePathHere");
string password = "password=";
foreach(password in source){
//Something with Regex Matching? Like...
if(Regex.isMatch(password, source)){

{
}
```

Like I said I have NO clue how to do this, I know it's nice to give some kind of attempt though.

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried?

Comment: I said in the post I have no idea what I'm doing with Regex,so that's why I need assistance. I would prefer an explanation with the code.

Comment: Do you really have no delimiter between `com` and `login` `myemail@gmail.comlogin=Amazon`?

Comment: Oh I changed it around now, so now it's just one line not back to back; so like: `"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.comlogin=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com"`

On each line

Answer (score 0):

This website is great for developing your regulgar expressions: http://regexhero.net/

Here's one way you could achiveve what you are looking to extract.

```
       var input =
            @"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.comlogin=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com";

        var pattern = @"login=(?<login>.*?)&password=(?<password>.*?)&r&email=(?<email>.*?)(?:(?=login)|$|\s)";

        foreach (Match match in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            var login = match.Groups["login"].Value;
            var password = match.Groups["password"].Value;
            var email = match.Groups["email"].Value;
            // Write your code here to do something with the values
        }
```

I'll explain how the last part of the expression works. (?:(?=login)|$|\s). Basically email will contain every character until either 'login', the end of an line, or white space has been found. The white space was just for testing and could removed.

Comment: Ok, ok I understand this, now just say for some reason the text file contains junk filler, aka like:
`jsdkkjakdjladksa;ldjs;ad"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com"dlskdl;akl;dsal;dl;sal;dk;alskdl;sakd;afjiodjf[eswofgoiudshfouidhsfouisfudsfghdspuifdsghp"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com"`
The above code isn't working for me, I saw there was a mistake in the Regex that I think I fixed, the input is only `"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com"` so the pattern should exclude the extra login at the end right?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the pattern was repeating itself, either right after each other, or on new lines. I'll explain it in the answer

Comment: Still not working out man, the text in the file is like `jsdkkjakdjladksa;ldjs;ad"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com‌​"dlskdl;akl;dsal;dl;sal;dk;alskdl;sakd;afjiodjf[eswofgoiudshfouidhsfouisfudsfghds‌​puifdsghp"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com"` with the " "'s by the way.

Comment: Wow, that is really random this "junk filler". Can we assume that after the "myemail@gmail.com" that the junk filler is enclosed with "'s, and then "login" follows  ??

Comment: Or Does "||" signify the beginning of the junk filler? I'm trying to establish some structure as to how the junk filler is added.

Comment: We can assume that after myemail@gmail.com, follows ""'s, but no 'login' does not start after that, it's just like the example; filler in between. The 'Filler' btw is just other personal data of mine I'd rather not put you know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56830/discussion-between-jonathon-lee-and-frank).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this next(using your 2 strings as example):

```
string source = "login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com";
string secondsource = @"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.comlogin=Amazon&password=MYPASS123&r&email=myemail@gmail.com";

string result = Regex.Match(source, @"(?<=password=)[a-zA-Z\\.\\r\\n0-9]*(?=&)").Value;
MatchCollection result2 = Regex.Matches(secondsource, @"(?<=password=)[a-zA-Z\\.\\r\\n0-9]*(?=&)");
```

Comment: Thank you very much but; I think you had an old version I refreshed the page, my comment below goes the same for you:

Comment: now just say for some reason the text file contains junk filler, aka like: `jsdkkjakdjladksa;ldjs;ad"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com‌​"dlskdl;akl;dsal;dl;sal;dk;alskdl;sakd;afjiodjf[eswofgoiudshfouidhsfouisfudsfghds‌​puifdsghp"login=Amazon&password=MYPASS&r&email=myemail@gmail.com"`

Comment: still gets me the 2 MYPASS.